# Condition for a quasi-isomorphism to be homotopy invertible

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

While I was reading a paper, I got stuck in a proposition which essentially uses the following fact.

Let $f\colon A^\bullet\rightarrow B^\bullet$ be a chain map between complexes in an abelian category $\mathbf{A}$ such that the morphism $$f_*\colon \mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(C,A)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(C,B)$$ is a quasi-isomorphism for every complex $C$ in $\mathbf{A}.$ Then $f$ is homotopy invertible.

I have never met such property and I do not find any reference. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related and/or a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483659/criterion-for-homotopy-invertibility ?